# Running solr server from php

Tags: php, solr, jetty

Currently, I have to navigate to the `example` directory of solr and execute `java -jar start.jar`.

However, I want users to have the ability of running the server automatically by selecting an option. Lets say,

```
1.The user downloads the `solr` directory on his/her server.
2.Enters the location of the example directory he/she just downloaded.
3.Selects/Clicks an option saying "Start Solr server".
4. And the server is started.
```

Is this possible? I'm looking to do this through `php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it via command line, you can do it via php's [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) assuming that is not disabled on your server.

**Note:** This is a very dangerous function if you allow user input to go through it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like the following command to do this. Just add the path to the given command:

```
<?php 
exec("nohup java -jar start.php > output.log 2>&1 &");

?>
```

nohup is important to decouple the solr process from your php request.

Your idea is dangerous, because you allow the user to enter any location to start their scripts. So you really need to think about path validation to ensure that only solr is started and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks. In my application I have many security features. Only the admin will have access to run such a script. I guess that will be okay.