# Best Practices for Apache SOLR - php Applicatoin

Tags: php, apache, security, solr, exec

I have successfully integrated Apache Solr into my web application via Solarium (which is awesome!) this question might belong on ServerFault but I'll give it a shot here anyway...

So as far as starting the Apache Solr Server I'm aware of a few options:

1. You can manually start it via command line with some sort of `java -jar start.jar` command
2. Or you can use that command through the php `exec()` function. [StackOverflow ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978524/running-solr-server-from-php)
3. Or include that in a start up script that automatically starts the server on system boot. [StackOverflow ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150767/how-to-start-solr-automatically)

The best practice imo would be to start solr on system start up through an automated script, then when the user attempts to use Solr, ping the server to ensure it is up and running, if it's not, use php `exec()` to try and start it back up.

**Questions:**

Both answers in the stackoverflow question about using the `exec()` function to accomplish this warn about security risks, but if I'm hard coding the path to use, how can this be a risk? What other security concerns should I have when using this method and how can I account for them?